Expected depth of random tree which randomly select the parent node for every node.
Consider using the following method to generate a tree:

Set node $1$ as the root;
For node $i$ ($i \in [2,n]$), randomly select the parent node in $[1,i)$.

(The expression of the interval here is not strict)
I can calculate the expected depth of node $n$, however, the expected depth of the tree is not simply the maximum of expected depth of each node.

(Edited) How to calculate the expected depth of node $n$?
Let $f_i$ be the expected depth of node $i$, specifically, let $f_1=1$.
Let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i$. We found that
$$ f_{n+1}=S_{n+1}-S_n=\dfrac{S_n}{n}+1. $$
And
$$ S_n=n\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{1}{i}\right). $$

Is anyone willing to provide a hint?
Thanks!
English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

You might chase down the references in the Wikipedia article.

Let $e(n)$ be the expected depth of a random tree with nodes $1,...,n$, constructed as specified. Then a brute force program yields the following data . . .
$$
\begin{array}
{|c|c|}
\hline
n&e(n)\
\hline
1&1\
\hline
2&2\
\hline
3&5/2=2.5\
\hline
4&3\
\hline
5&27/8=3.375\
\hline
6&221/60\approx 3.683333333\
\hline
7&2849/720\approx 3.956944444\
\hline
8&7061/1680\approx 4.202976190\
\hline
9&22297/5040\approx 4.424007936\
\hline
10&59921/12960\approx 4.623533951;\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
